# Delay commands after defined time from initial in python

Tags: python, sleep

I am trying to delay commands with a delta from the initial time of execution. In other words, I want a start time point that the rest of the commands are delayed in reference to that start time point. Example:

```
print("start")

# command that delays for a minute since the start
print("it's been a 1 min")

# command that delays for n minute since the start
print("it's been n min")
```

I am trying to switch from `sleep()`, but haven't found something that fits what I need. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: ```import time  
time.sleep(give time in seconds)``` For more check out [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import time
initial_time = int(time.time()) #frame of reference in seconds

def delta_sleep(s):
    """
    Parameters:
        s: seconds since elapsed to sleep until
    """
    if int(time.time()) > initial_time + s:
        # check if the delta time has already passed
        return
    else:
        # find time needed to sleep to reach the specified param 's'
        needed_sleep = (initial_time+s) - int(time.time())
        time.sleep(needed_sleep)

# example

print("The program has started")

delta_sleep(5)

print("Five seconds have passed")

delta_sleep(8)

print("8 seconds have passed")

delta_sleep(1) # does not sleep at all
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Didn't think to use the the current time as int. Thank you.